# Inconsistent bloginfo information

Tags: theme-development, bloginfo

I'm doing a little bit of work on a theme I just inherited from another developer. The site just broke, and I'm trying to fix it.

You can see the site here: [www.bowlingventures.com](http://www.bowlingventures.com)

What's happening is this. As you can see, the home page loads unstyled. All of the images are being pushed out using "bloginfo('template_directory');" If you click on one of the links to another page, you'll see that that page loads correctly. Inspecting the page source, the paths to the image directory differ slightly. Both paths are output using "bloginfo('template_directory');" Additionally, when logged in, the home page loads just fine. How is this possible? Also, I tried adding some information to the header.php template file to be printed on every page. This information was only visible on the non-home pages.

Heads up, the site is *slow*  I'll be fixing that later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that your secondary pages link to images using a URL like:

`http://www.bowlingventures.com/BVc_13/wp-content/themes/bowlingventures/images/m2u.jpg`

whereas your home page uses:

`http://www.bowlingventures.com/wp-content/themes/bowlingventures/images/m2u.jpg`

Not sure this helps, but perhaps this will help someone else figure out what is going on.

Are you sure that the home page is being loaded from WordPress?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. On the secondary pages, the "BVc_13" part of the url is correct. The homepage omits that. I am positive. At least, there is a home.php template file in the theme directory that mirrors the code that the browser sees...

Comment: What's in the "BVc_13" directory on your server? Is there a full WordPress install?

Comment: It's the directory where all of the Wordpress stuff is. In the root directory of the server, there's a php file that includes stuff from the Wordpress folder.

Comment: That's likely the problem. The files should be in the root of the directory, or at least they should not be included from another file within the directory. This is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'll try that. It was installed that way for "security reasons" I'm not really clear on...

Comment: So secure that you cannot even access your own images ;)

Comment: Clarification, the index.php file is outside of the wordpress folder. Otherwise, it pretty much does what it's supposed to.